# Vowpal Wabbit - How to get prediction probabilities from contextual bandit model on a test sample

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Given a trained contextual bandit model, how can I retrieve a  prediction vector on test samples?

For example, let's say I have a train set named "train.dat" containing lines formatted as below

```
1:-1:0.3 | a b c  # <action:cost:probability | features> 
2:2:0.3 | a d d 
3:-1:0.3 | a b e
....
```

And I run below command.

```
vw -d train.dat --cb 30 -f cb.model --save_resume
```

This produces a file, 'cb.model'. Now, let's say I have a test dataset as below

```
| a d d 
| a b e
```

I'd like to see probabilities as below

```
0.2 0.7 0.1
```

The interpretation of these probabilities would be that action 1 should be picked 20% of the time, action 2 - 70%, and action 3 - 10% of the time.

Is there a way to get something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to this since I haven't used `--cb`, but the vowpal-wabbit source tree on github has several `--cb` examples in `test/RunTests` with data-sets and results, so perhaps you should start there?  Another trick that I often use is the option `-a` (aka `--audit`) which outputs the weights of features on stderr as `vw` runs.  This can help gain deep visibility into the model in real-time. HTH.

Comment: @arielf Thank you for your reply as always! I will check out the --audit option. The relevant test seemed to be Test #121, where they use "--cb_explore k" with -p flag to output predictions, but I'm not sure what exactly the predictions are. More precisely, i'm not sure if the predictions represent probabilities over each of "k" actions, or probabilities over each "k" policies.

Answer (score 5):

When you use "--cb K", the prediction is the optimal arm/action based on argmax policy, which is a static policy.

When using "--cb_explore K", the prediction output contains the probability for each arm/action. Depending the policy you pick, the probabilities are calculated differently.

Comment: With "--cb_explore K" what estimator does VW use to predict the rewards for each arm ? Is it dr or ips or iwr or dm 
How to specify the type of estimator to use in the "--cb_explore K"? can I specify the --cb_type flag ? 
something like "--cb_explore k --cb_type dm" ?

Answer (score 2):

If you send those lines to a daemon running your model, you'd get just that. You send a context, and the reply is a probability distribution across the number of allowed actions, presumably comprising the "recommendation" provided by the model.

Say you have 3 actions, like in your example. Start a contextual bandits daemon:

```
vowpalwabbit/vw -d train.dat --cb_explore 3 -t --daemon --quiet --port 26542
```

Then send a context to it:

```
| a d d
```

You'll get just what you want as the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the Workspace Class, initialize the object and then call the method predict(prediction_type: int). Below are the corresponding parameter values

```
class PredictionType(IntEnum):
SCALAR = pylibvw.vw.pSCALAR
SCALARS = pylibvw.vw.pSCALARS
ACTION_SCORES = pylibvw.vw.pACTION_SCORES
ACTION_PROBS = pylibvw.vw.pACTION_PROBS
MULTICLASS = pylibvw.vw.pMULTICLASS
MULTILABELS = pylibvw.vw.pMULTILABELS
PROB = pylibvw.vw.pPROB
MULTICLASSPROBS = pylibvw.vw.pMULTICLASSPROBS
DECISION_SCORES = pylibvw.vw.pDECISION_SCORES
ACTION_PDF_VALUE = pylibvw.vw.pACTION_PDF_VALUE
PDF = pylibvw.vw.pPDF
ACTIVE_MULTICLASS = pylibvw.vw.pACTIVE_MULTICLASS
NOPRED = pylibvw.vw.pNOPRED
```