# Vowpal Wabbit: Using --top k flag

Tags: vowpalwabbit

This question is related to my [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669363/vowpal-wabbit-how-to-get-prediction-probabilities-from-contextual-bandit-model) about retrieving prediction probabilities.

My goal is to use the VW's contextual bandit module to train a model that can predict the best actions given new test samples. What I want to do though, is to retrieve **"top k" actions**, **not just a single action** as in a standard contextual mult-armed bandit (CMAB) setting.

I am wondering about the usage of "--top arg" flag. In the vw --help, it is listed under Reduction option as below:

```
  --top arg                             top k recommendation
```

I am trying to use this flag with contextual bandit module with the following approach.

First, I train an initial model with offline logged data in train.dat (30 actions were available; hence --cb 30)

```
vw -d train.dat --cb 30 -f cb.model --save_resume
```

Then, I tried to test this model to retrieve top 5 recommendations with test samples in test.dat

```
vw -t -d test.dat -i cb.model --top 5 -p test.predict
```

However, my test.predict file contains only 1 recommendation. I would expect to see 5 actions, given --top 5 flag. I am wondering what I am missing in regards to my understanding of using the '--top' flag.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work.  Separate reductions in `vw` (both `cb` and `topk` are reductions to the core classification mechanism) usually cannot compose as if they were orthogonal regular options in the core algorithms.  It is a limitation of `vw`.  See Zhen Qin's presentation on --topk  at:   https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Zhen.pdf   (the relevant slide is 16 of 30)